# How to manage UIPagecontrol not to exceed the view bounds when count is more?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I am using a pagecontrol to display the number of pages.My actual problem is,
If i am having some 10 pages,the pagecontrol is displaying properly.If i am having some 100 pages pagecontrol will go out of bounds.Is it possible to overcome this problem and display total number of pages.
If is there any way please help.

Comment: hi smith did u got the solution. I'm also facing the same Issue. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should create a custom view to display page numbers (with navigation [move first, last] buttons etc). UIPageControl will not handle large number of pages..
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745333/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-a-uipagecontrol-that-has-so-many-dots-they-dont) thread as well.